SQL Server + convert to text to HEX UTF16 Little Endian
I've done many tests and some research, but I can't find a solution.
In SQL Server, how can I convert a string to HEX UTF16 LittleEndian to have a result like this?
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 'P384992') as key

Actual result:

0x50333834393932

Needed result:

0x5000330038003400390039003200


N'P384992' perhaps? but this won't be UTF16 nor hex really, it will be binary usc2 =)

If you COLLATE to a collation with supplementary characters, it would be UTF-16, @siggemannen .

The main problem here is you are using a varchar for your string. varchars use the collation of the database, but the vast majority are single byte character collations, and so use code pages like ANSI-1252. As a result converting a varchar to a varbinary is going to yield a single byte per character.
To get UTF-16, you need to be using an nvarchar. As siggemannen notes, just popping a N at the start might not yield a UTF-16 value, but a USC-2 value. To get a UTF-16 value, you would need to ensure you use a collation that uses supplemenary characters, which is denoted by SC in the collation name. For example Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC (Latin1-General-100, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive, supplementary characters).
So, that would look like this:
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), N'P384992' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC) as [key];

If you, ironically, are only going to have ANSI characters in your string, then just using an nvarchar literal will be fine, as USC-2 and UTF-16 completely overlap.


Create a Scalar Function in SQL Server:
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnConvertStringToUTF16LEHex (@inputString NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARBINARY(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @utf16le VARBINARY(MAX) = 0x

    DECLARE @i INT = 1
    DECLARE @len INT = LEN(@inputString)

    WHILE @i <= @len
    BEGIN
        SET @utf16le = @utf16le + CONVERT(VARBINARY(2), UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@inputString, @i, 1)))
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    RETURN @utf16le
END 
GO


Call the Function with Your Input:
You can then call this function with your input string:
SELECT dbo.fnConvertStringToUTF16LEHex('P384992') as key


This should List item d return the needed result:

"Create a Scalar Function in SQL Server:" Why? What's wrong with CONVERT/CAST? "WHILE @i <= @len" WHY?! There's literally no need for an obscure function, and there's never a reason for that obscure function to be a non-inlinable with a WHILE loop in it.
